# creating realtime 2D maps of indoor environment

Tags: c++, matlab

I am using ultrasonic sensors to get the data about the indoor environment i.e the distance of the from each wall . I  want draw a realtime map of the surronding environment using that can u please guide that which software or which library is best suited for this purpose

Comment: what purpose? have you already extracted the measures and you want to elaborate them or you want to actually take the data from some hd peripheral?

Comment: Too vague. How do you get the data? Where do you draw the map? What does realtime mean, exactly? What kind of map do you want to draw? Examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenCV. It has everything you need for image processing. Could be an overkill tho, but I wouldn't mind it.

http://opencv.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want realtime map, I'd use Labview->embedded MATLAB code / C++. Labview has excellent hardware/peripheral support and operations, and you can embed custom code in the signal flow representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like arduino or raspberry or any other such electronics kit to capture the ultrasound data, you can send the data to the serial port and then use Matlab to read from that serial port and use it to plot a live map. A good step by step  example of how this can be done is available at [Matlab Arduino org website](http://www.matlabarduino.org/serial-communication.html)